# How to integrate option tree latest version 2.6.0 theme in child theme of twenty seventy theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to Integrate option Tree plugin in my child theme of twenty seventeen but Its not not working.

bellow is the code after adding option tree in child theme.

```
// Integrate OptionTree
add_filter( 'OT_CHILD_THEME_MODE', '__return_true' );
/* Theme Options */
require_once( get_template_directory() . '/option-tree/ot-loader.php' );

// Hide Documentation Page
add_filter( 'ot_show_pages', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'ot_show_new_layout', '__return_false' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the option-tree directory in the root of your theme. For example, the server path would be **/wp-content/themes/theme-name/option-tree/.**
Add the following code to the beginning of your functions.php.

```
/**
 * Required: set 'ot_theme_mode' filter to true.
 */
add_filter( 'ot_theme_mode', '__return_true' );

/**
 * Required: include OptionTree.
 */
require( trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) . 'option-tree/ot-loader.php' );
```

Comment: Yes this code work fine when integrated in directly theme.

but when tried same in child theme id dont work.

Can You please Help me out for child Theme integration with option tree.

Comment: could you please show me your child theme function.php